# Selenium/Python Disable ChromeDriver updates and Revert Version

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I've been running a selenium/python script on Windows 7 x64 for a few weeks.  Google Chrome is installed on the machine with version 109 (last supported win 7 version) with browser updates disabled.  Occasionally, I would get messages like this when instatiating ChromeDriver;

```
[WDM] - Downloading:   0%|          | 0.00/6.30M [00:00<?, ?B/s]
[WDM] - Downloading:  43%|####3     | 2.71M/6.30M [00:00<00:00, 26.0MB/s]
[WDM] - Downloading: 100%|##########| 6.30M/6.30M [00:00<00:00, 38.5MB/s]
```

which as I understand it is some automatic update of ChromeDriver (?)

The most recent update has broken my script, and now I get the error;

selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 109.0.5414.120 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

I need help with two things;

1. How do I get ChromeDriver back to a version that supports Chrome 109?
2. [more importantly] How do I prevent this automatic update of ChromeDriver from happening again?

I can probably figure out #1.  I need definitive help with #2.  Most of the searches come back with discussions of how to prevent the browser from updating, not how to prevent the call to

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
    options=options,
    desired_capabilities=caps
)
```

from triggering a (package?) update.

Comment: I did figure out the directory where multiple ChromeDriver versions were saved and was able to revert that to 109.   The messages about downloading something still appear though.

Answer (score 1):

Since `selenium` `4.10.0`, the driver manager is now included and out of beta, so you might not need to use ChromeDriverManager at all, which may solve your issue:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# ...
driver.quit()
```

(Add `options` as needed)

But you can also try the [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) Driver Manager. `pip install seleniumbase`, and then run with `python`:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(browser="chrome", incognito=True)
```

Options are handled via different args. If you have Chrome 109 installed, it will get chromedriver 109 if that's not the version on your PATH.

Comment: Thanks.  There are  many tutorials written over the years that seem to use different methodologies and syntax in this area, so it is hard to know what is current and best practice.